# Why do I get NaN for sum when type of var is number?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects from which I access numbers that I use to form another var named "total" which is a sum of all those numbers. When I check the type of each number it says "number" but for "total" it says NaN.

Here is the code:

```
items = [];
total: number;

collect = () => {
  this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.cart);
  this.items.forEach(item =>{
  this.total += item.cena;
  console.log(this.total);
  });
}
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: What data are in `localStorage.cart`?

Comment: You haven't initialised `this.total`, so it's just `undefined` by default.

Comment: Objects from which I select number which is item.cena.

Comment: Well that's right. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That might be fine but any number added to `undefined` produces `NaN`.